routes error on nested routes - react navigation
<NavigationContainer
    theme={navigation_theme}
    linking={{
        prefixes: ["https://startja.agenciaboz.com.br", "http://localhost:8081"],
        config: {
            screens: {
                home: {
                    path: "",
                    screens: {
                        login: "login",
                        budget: "budget",
                        budgetSuccess: "budget/success",
                        budgetFailed: "budget/failed",
                        forgotPassword: "forgot-password",
                        codeVerification: "forgot-password/verification",
                        resetPassword: "forgot-password/reset",
                        successComponent: "forgot-password/success",
                    },
                },
                notfound: "*",
            },
        },
    }}
    documentTitle={{ formatter: (options, route) => `Start Já - ${route?.name}` }}
>

In this component I'm trying to nest some routes inside others, but I'm getting the following error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'screens' does not exist in type 'Omit<PathConfig<{}>, "screens" | "initialRouteName">'.ts(2353)
Providers.tsx(24, 25): The expected type comes from property 'home' which is declared here on type 'PathConfigMap<{ home: unknown; systemChooser: unknown; admin: unknown; resale: unknown; system: unknown; userSettings: unknown; customersSettings: unknown; resalesSettings: unknown; adminMasterSettings: unknown; notfound: unknown; }>'
⚠ Error (TS2353)  | 
Object literal may only specify known properties, and screens does not exist in type

what is the correct way to do this?

You need to configure TypeScript for React Navigation so it knows about the screens inside home
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#specifying-default-types-for-usenavigation-link-ref-etc
